# ¿Cúal es la diferencia entre subir una imagen con el public path que con File Storage?

Tags: php, laravel

Hola tengo un api en laravel que sube una imagen, el primer metodo que utilice fue public_path para subir la imagen a la carpeta public y este fue el codigo

```
$filename = time() . "." . $request->image->extension();
$request->image->move(public_path('images'), $filename);
```

Y el sube la imagen a la carpeta **public/images** con el nombre que le di.

El otro metodo utilizando File Storage es

```
$request->image->store('public/images');
```

La diferencia es que la imagen ahora esta en **storage/app/public/images**, y el nombre lo asigna automaticamente.

Mi pregunta es si hay alguna ventaja usar el File Storage a utilizar el public_path.
¿Es lo mismo? ¿Es mejor utilizar public_path? Esa es mi pregunta

Answer (score 0):

No es que uno sea mejor que otro, depende mucho del uso que le des o necesites. La diferencia radica en el acceso a esos archivos.

Si utilizas `public_path` los archivos que subas estarán en tu directorio publico lo cual lo hace accesible para todos. Esto es usado para archivos estáticos o de uso público.

En cambio, si utilizas `File Storage` puedes controlar mejor quien accede a estos archivos. Es mayormente usado para subir información sensible o datos del usuario.